# Themes no longer applied to Wingpanel menus and certain default apps

Tags: wingpanel, themes, horus

I recently installed some OS updates through AppCenter and both my OS (GTK) theme and icon theme aren't applied to the Wingpanel and its menus anymore. Some (not all) default apps are also showing the same behaviour. See screenshots at the end of the question for examples.

My themes are configured using [`pantheon-tweaks`](https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks), which is on the latest available version (`1.1.0`). I've tried multiple themes, but the ones in the screenshots here are specifically [Skeuos](https://github.com/daniruiz/skeuos-gtk) (GTK) and [Kora](https://github.com/bikass/kora) (icons). Both are on the latest version.

Is this due to a recent change in some of these apps? Can I modify the files in these themes myself to try and fix the issue? I'd happily make an issue (or PR) to the themes to help resolve it, but I wouldn't know where to look.

I'm happy to provide any additional info you may need.

The themes are applied correctly to:

- Screenshot
- Files
- Calendar
- Settings
- AppCenter
- Photos

The themes are *not* applied to:

- The entire Wingpanel + submenus
- Mail
- Calculator

#### Comparison Screenshots

- ##### Screenshot tool (OS theme applied correctly) vs Calculator (OS theme no longer applied):

  [image: Screenshot vs Calculator]
- ##### Applications menu in Wingpanel (both OS and icon themes no longer applied):

  [image: Applications menu]
- ##### App icons in Dock (icon theme applied correctly):

  [image: Dock]
- ##### Files (OS and icon themes applied correctly) vs Wingpanel Calendar (OS theme no longer applied):

  [image: Files vs Wingpanel Calendar]